# Laptop not charging nor turning on

Tags: windows-10, shutdown, troubleshooting, charging, hp-laptop

Since a few weeks ago I'm facing a issue with my HP laptop. It's almost a year old.

It used to work fine but few weeks ago, when I was working on it, it suddenly turned off without any warning.

I tried to charge it but nothing happened, none of the lights (including the one near the charging port) turned on.

I searched on internet and tried holding the power button for a minute or so but without any sign of progress.

After a few days later, I plugged in my laptop and it started charging as well as turned on.

Then again after some days, the issue showed up and went in the same way as it came.

This used to happen atleast once a week, and this week also it happened, just a few days ago.

I'm really worried about what's wrong with it.

Edit 1: I forgot to mention that everytime my laptop would start after such breakdowns, a CMOS checksum error message would be displayed on my screen

Edit 2: I discharged my laptop completely (via USB port) yesterday night. And today it started. I have downloaded The Support Assitant for HP so now will do various checks and tests to figure out what was/is wrong with it

Comment: Is the laptop under warranty?  If so, it should be examined by an HP warranty provider.

Comment: @DaveM I contacted the HP guys. They said it's out of warranty. More over, since my district is under lockdown due to COVID-19, I dont have any access to any laptop repairing person.

Comment: It may not be easy to check but is it possible the voltage being supplied to your residence is lower than normal due to lockdown? Have seen this locally(not lockdown related) where a local transformer was faulty and voltage was about 20% lower than expected.  Systems had issues.

Comment: It doesnt seem so that the voltage is lower than usual, cuz all other appliances are working properly. Moreover, my laptop wasnt out of charge when it got shut down. So it should start on battery power atleast, but it is not :(

Comment: If the problem suddenly occurs and then goes away it might be an overheating issue. How long does the "no reaction to anything" state after it has switched itself of remains? Minutes, hours or longer?

Comment: It usually lasts for 2 to 3 days... but now 5 days have passed since the last shut down without any sign of progress

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the battery is seated correctly. try unplugging and replugging the battery. i think the battery might come out of the space when it switches off, and cause it's not in the laptop, it can't charge.

Comment: Actually battery is not user-removable. I can do that but battery and the connection doesnt seem to be an issue because the usb ports are working and they do charge if I connect my phone.

Comment: Well, I think that something must be not correctly seated in there. It would be weird that it turns off but still charges your phone. It can't be the screen connection, cause the lights go off. I'll think of a few more.